# is it okay to expose Stripe Publishable key in the frontend like this

Tags: stripe-payments

As per documents, one needs to wrap the app component with Stripe elements like this

```
    <div>
      <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
    
          <ToastContainer />
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
</ToastContainer >
          </Router>
            </Switch>

<Elements/>
```

and stripePromise gets value like this

```
const stripePromise = loadStripe(sk.........);
```

Here is sk.... is the Stripe Publishable key. Since I'm new to programming, I'm wondering whether it is safe to expose the Publishable key like this.

If not, how do you wrap the app with Stripe Elements and pass Stripe promise?

Comment: It's all over Stripe's sample apps, e.g. https://github.com/stripe/elements-examples/blob/master/js/index.js

Answer (score 4):

Yes Stripe Publishable key is made for public usage, you can use it in your client-side code and can be exposed with the user. In other words, it can be publicly-accessible in your web or mobile app’s client-side code.

[1] [https://stripe.com/docs/keys#obtain-api-keys:~:text=pk_test_51LFx4JF1SIVBSMvIiQmcLaJqQkmWpPi0EPxrVdMyslzvPbh9Hu77WZTnbBp9p46zXlJa2MRt8HpZsT6jVNraOmjw00ZirV6oRo-,On%20the%20client%2Dside,-%3A%20Can%20be%20publicly](https://stripe.com/docs/keys#obtain-api-keys:%7E:text=pk_test_51LFx4JF1SIVBSMvIiQmcLaJqQkmWpPi0EPxrVdMyslzvPbh9Hu77WZTnbBp9p46zXlJa2MRt8HpZsT6jVNraOmjw00ZirV6oRo-,On%20the%20client%2Dside,-%3A%20Can%20be%20publicly)

Answer (score 3):

I would have commented only, but since I don't have enough reputation points, here it goes:

What you have shown in your example code is a SECRET key: '**sk**.........'. That is not Stripe publishable key! A secret 'sk........' key should be kept secret.

A publishable key would be something like "**pk**.........". Such questions is misleading, I hope someone edits it.

From Stripe about the secret 'sk.....' key:

> On the server side: Must be secret and stored securely in your web or mobile app’s server-side code (such as in an environment variable or credential management system)...

From Stripe about the publishable 'pk.....' key:

> On the client side: Can be publicly accessible in your web or mobile app’s client-side code

Retrieved from https://stripe.com/docs/keys

Answer (score 0):

The stripe docs expressly recommend using your publishable key in frontend client code.

https://stripe.com/docs/keys

"On the client-side: Can be publicly-accessible in your web or mobile app’s client-side code (such as checkout.js) to securely collect payment information such as with Stripe Elements. By default, Stripe Checkout securely collects payment information."